# Running C++ program on API call in AWS

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs

I have a C++ algorithm that I want to execute every time an API call is made to API Gateway, this algo takes a bit to run, something between 1min and 30mins, and I need to run one instance of this algorithm for every API call, so I need to parallelize multiple instances of this program.

Since is C++, and I wanted to avoid using EC2 instances, I was planning to use a Docker image to pack my program, and then use Lambdas to execute it, but since the maximum time limit of a Lambda is 15mins, I'm thinking this is not the right way.
I was investigating about using ECS, but I'm a bit skeptical since from various docs I understood ECS is for running "perpetual" apps, like web servers, etc.

So my question is, what's the best way, in your opinion, to make a REST API that executes suck a long C++ task?

Another important point is that I need to pass an input file to this C++ program, and this file is built when the API is called, so I can't incorporate it inside the Docker image, is there a way to solve this?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If your computation is resumable then you could run in a lambda and shortly before the lambda times out, launch a new lambda to complete the computation.

You don't need docker for this, lambda can execute native executables ([if compiled correctly](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/))

If this isn't possible then a more involved solution would be to push jobs onto an SQS queue then have instances of your app in ECS which pulls items off the queue and executes the required processing.

You can scale the number of ECS instances based on the size of the SQS queue.

For your input file it's probably easiest to have your API write it into S3 then your processor can download it from there.

Comment: Unfortunately my task is not resumable, so I don't think using Lambdas would be feasible.
I think ECS with SQS queue is the best way to handle my task.